# Define and Apply Template in After Effects RenderQueue Object

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

I was wondering if anyone knows if defining and applying a template to a renderQueue item is possible in AE. The documentation has methods to easily apply a pre-existing template but I'd like to define the template within the script.

My script so far adds the **activeItem** and starts the queue but that means the last template used is applied.

```
renderComp.onClick = function(){
  app.project.renderQueue.items.add(app.project.activeItem);
  app.project.renderQueue.render();
}
```

Thanks in advance!
I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the After Effects CS6 Scripting Guide (page 112):

### OutputModule saveAsTemplate() method

```
app.project.renderQueue.item(index).outputModule(index).saveAsTemplate(name)
```

#### Description

Saves this output module as a template and adds it to the templates array.
Parameters `name` A string containing the name of the new template.
Returns Nothing.

---

Since CC 2014 you have access to these settings below.

> what’s new and changed in After Effects CC 2014 (13.0) | After Effects region of interest
>   http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/2014/04/new-changed-after-effects-cc-2014.html

**scripting access to render settings and output module settings**. 
Added: RenderQueueItem object getSetting, setSetting methods
Added: OutputModule object getSetting, setSetting methods
Added: RenderQueueItem object getSettings, setSettings methods
Added: OutputModule object getSettings, setSettings methods

Comment: I understand this step two of what I am asking but I want to define the output module and save it as this specific output module doesn't currently exist as a template.

Comment: Got it, this looks like what I need, thanks so much!